# Dependency error while setting up spark with java in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am new to spark and Java. I was trying to setup the spark environment in Eclipse using maven dependency. I am using Java 1.8 with Scala 2.11.7. I gave created a Scala project in Eclipse and created a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I am getting an error as **"Failure to transfer org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced."**

Comment: The artifact spark-core_2.11 does not exist, use spark-core_2.10 for the artifactid

Answer (score 0):

I am new too. These r my steps working with eclipse, scala 2.11, maven and spark: 1.- Create a maven project 2.- Use this POM as basic orientation https://github.com/entradajuan/Spark0/blob/master/Spark0/pom.xml 3.- Convert the project to Scala: right buton->configure->convert to Scala 4.- Then create a package in src/main/java 5.- Create an scala object with its def main in the new package

So far I am always starting the same way. I dont use Java in my projects.
It works fine also when running maven build "clean install" for getting jar.

Comment: Juani: Thanks, it helped.